# Regarding Transition Probability Matrix

Tags: probability, matlab, markov-process

I am calculating transition probability matrix (TPM) using `hmmestimate` command of MATALB.
The simple vector `a=[ 1     1     1     1     3     3     3     2     1     3]` and for this the TPM is

```
hmmestimate(a,a)

ans =
0.6000         0    0.4000
1.0000         0         0
     0    0.3333    0.6667
```

I believe it is calculated as : (1,3) element:

```
(# of 1->3 transitions)/(total # of 1) = 2/5 = 0.4
```

Same rule follows for all the elements. Then why not for element (3,2) and (3,3). For example: (3,2) element:

```
(# of 3->2 transitions)/(total # of 3) = 1/4 = 0.25
```

but the transition matrix calculated by MATLAB entry 0.33. For `(3,3)`, according to my calculation the entry should have been `(2/4)=0.5` but it is `0.6667`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include the $3$ on the end in the count of $3$s because it has no successor. If you have $n$ values, there are only $n-1$ transitions.